# Google Maps event listeners not working properly in a Javascript 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, events, maps

I'm trying to set up a Google map instance where some content is dynamically generated for a set of points.

Right now, I'm using a for loop to loop through any number of latitude and longitude values and create markers are those points on the map.

I'm trying to add info windows that correspond to each of these markers and have them pop up when you click the markers.

However, I'm having a little bit of trouble. It looks like my for loop that creates basically everything is working without fail, apart from the eventListener section:

```
function drawMap(points) {
    popUps = new Array();
    infoWindows = new Array();
    positions = new Array();

    contents = '<div id = "content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<p id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Position</h1>' +
        '</div>';

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contents
    });

    for( i = 0; i < points.length; i++ ){
        positions[i] = new google.maps.Marker({ position: 
        latlng[i], 
        map:map, 
        title:"Position"});

        popUps[i] = '<div id = "content">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<p id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Position</h1>' +
            '</div>';

        infoWindows[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: popUps[i]
        });

    // everything up to this point works fine, I can reference it all manually
    // and get back the expected value.

        google.maps.event.addListener(positions[i], 'click', function(){
            infoWindows[i].open(map, positions[i]);                 
        });

    // if I change each instance of "i" to "0" here, I'll get a popup on the
    // expected marker containing content that I defined in this for loop. Same for
    //  "1" and "2." But "i" doesn't work.
    }
}
```

where "map" is an instance of google.maps.Map and each instance of popUps will differ in the final product.

I call this function when the page loads, which adds positions and markers to my map:

```
drawMap([[13.283 , 162.232], [18.232 , 112.223], [17.233, 80.293]]);
```

Does anyone know why I'm unable to create eventListeners dynamically? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance. :)

Edit:

Turns out, the requirements here are only to have the divs pop up when the page loads. I didn't even need the event listener...

However, both answers were good and helped me figure out how to make the original code work, so thanks. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a function to add the maps listener, after your `infowindow` declaration. The function will create a closure and freeze the `i` value passed into it.

```
...
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contents
    });

var addListener = function (i) {

google.maps.event.addListener(positions[i], 'click', function(){
        infoWindows[i].open(map, positions[i]);                 
    });
   ...

}
```

Then call it in your `for` loop:

```
addListener(i);
```

Comment: this is really a good idea! would have never thought of it - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The inner function is closing over the *variable* `i`. At the end of the for-loop all the `i`s will be points.length. This is a very common Javascript gotcha:

[JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: So, this makes it so that each variable that I have referencing "i" will reference a separate variable? Like, making for loops for "i," "j," "k," etc? If I'm understanding this correctly, shouldn't I be getting a popup on points[2] when I use "i," in this case? Thanks for your response! I'm just a little confused. :)

Comment: In the example I linked, the `i` in the event handler is the i from createFunc. This means each call to createFunct gets its own i instead of sharing the i from the for-loop.