# Passing values in for loop to event listeners- Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looping through Markers with Google Maps API v3 Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670356/looping-through-markers-with-google-maps-api-v3-problem)

I have a loop in which I extract some data from an array element, then add an event listener for each iteration. But I need to pass these values to each associated listener but I end up having only the last array item values in the listener. I have tried to understand from ["this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809009/google-maps-event-listeners-not-working-properly-in-a-javascript-for-loop) but the solution seems not suitable in my case and I am confused. This is the code that I have:

```
for(var i=0;i<route.length;i++)
{
  var input= route[i];
  var sdata= input.split("@",19)
  //Some code
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',showiwindow);
}

function showiwindow(event)
{
  var input= event.latLng;
  //some code 
  ...
  document.getElementById('<%= lbl1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sdata[1];
  document.getElementById('<%= lbl2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sdata[2];
  document.getElementById('<%= lbl3.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sdata[3];
  document.getElementById('<%= lbl4.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sdata[4];     
  ......
}
```

When I click on a marker I only get the values of the last iteration. Coming back to the solution in that link, how do I pass the array along with the iteration value that is `i`. Kindly refer to the link of what I meant.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis: I think the link that I gave in my question was much more suitable to state as duplicate than the one that you provided. But let me tell you I am confused with the method that they followed to solve so had to put the question.

Comment: @Cdeez have a read of this -> http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/ you need to implement a closure, this link explains them very well (IMO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
for(var i=0;i<route.length;i++)
{
  var input= route[i];
  var sdata= input.split("@",19)
  //Some code
  showiwindow(sdata);
}

function showiwindow(sdata)
{
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', function(event) {
    var input= event.latLng;
    //some code 
    ...
    document.getElementById('<%= lbl1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sdata[1];
    document.getElementById('<%= lbl2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sdata[2];
    document.getElementById('<%= lbl3.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sdata[3];
    document.getElementById('<%= lbl4.ClientID %>').innerHTML = sdata[4];     
    ......
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the various links you have provided. Finally got a clear picture of how to deal with it:

```
for(var i=0;i<route.length;i++)
{
  var input= route[i];
  var sdata= input.split("@",19)
  //Some code
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',showiwindow(sdata));
}

function showiwindow(rdata)
{
  return function(){
  .....//some code
  document.getElementById('<%= lbl4.ClientID %>').innerHTML =rdata[4];
  .....
  };
}
```