# infowindows update from xml

Tags: xml, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have this code which load a xml file and push some markers into the map. This xml file is called again every 5 seconds and I update the position of the markers using marker.setPosition, what I want is to update the infowindows when I click over a marker. The problem now is that is always showing the first data loaded at the beginning. So if anyone know how to code it I would be very grateful.

```
    //<![CDATA[

var gmarkers = []; 
var map = null;
var infoWindow = null;
var markerclusterer = null;


var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function createMarker(latlng, imei, alias, speed, timestamp, estado, conectado, altitude, angle, soloFecha, hora, html, fechaUk) {
if(estado == 1)
image = '/artworks/icons/truck_green3.png';
else
image = '/artworks/icons/truck_red.png';
var textoLabel= html
var contentString = html;
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
position: latlng,
icon: image,
draggable: true,
// map: map,
labelContent: textoLabel,
labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(40, 0),
labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
labelStyle: {opacity: 0.50},
zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
});


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+2);
    map.setCenter(latlng);
    });

gmarkers.push(marker);

}//end function createMarker

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}//end function picks up the click


// create the map
function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
zoom: 12,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.169619,-3.756981),
mapTypeControl: true,
mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
navigationControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                        myOptions);
}// end create the map

setInterval(getMarkers, 5000); // call every 5 seconds the function getMarkers

function getMarkers() {
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
infowindow.close();
});
// Read the data from example.xml
downloadUrl("vehiculos.asp", function(doc) {
var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  // obtain the attribues of each marker
  var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
  var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  var imei = markers[i].getAttribute("imei");
  var alias = markers[i].getAttribute("alias");
  var speed= markers[i].getAttribute("speed");
  var timestamp= markers[i].getAttribute("timestamp");
  var estado= markers[i].getAttribute("estado");
  var conectado= markers[i].getAttribute("conectado");
  var altitude= markers[i].getAttribute("altitude");
  var angle= markers[i].getAttribute("angle");
  var soloFecha= markers[i].getAttribute("soloFecha");
  var hora= markers[i].getAttribute("hora");
  var fechaUk= markers[i].getAttribute("fechaUk");
  var html="<b>"+alias+"</b><br> a una velocidad de "+speed+" km/h <br/>     ultima posicion  a las: "+timestamp;


    // start, check if marker is already created, if so we update it, if not we create it
     if (gmarkers[i] != undefined)
             gmarkers[i].setPosition(point);

     else
            var marker = createMarker(point, imei, alias, speed, timestamp, estado, conectado, altitude, angle, soloFecha, hora, html, fechaUk);
    // end, check if marker is already created, if so we update it, if not we create it
}

markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);

});
}//end function getMarkers
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [update infowindows when calling again a xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156995/update-infowindows-when-calling-again-a-xml-file)