# Showing a content Div on hover of a marker in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have markers set on my Google map and on Hover of that particular marker i want to show a window which consists of some images that are related to that particular place.

As well i need to have a carousel affect for that images if they can not be accommodated in the div space..

how do i do that?

Comment: See the solution provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you an idea of how to do it-

See this example in the documentation for Infowindow-

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

The example uses a `click` event on the marker to open the infowindow

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Since you desire a `mouse over`, changing the event name will suffice

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
```

For placing an image inside the infowindow,
set the content of infowindow with a `<IMG> tag` as-

```
content: '<IMG ID="imgHolder" BORDER="1" SRC="myimage.jpg">
```

Comment: FYI, the infowindow will expand if the size of image is larger than `247px`. 247px is the minimum width of an infowindow.

Comment: my my Info window is being shown for the last Marker where ever i mouseover.

Comment: Thats the classic closure problem which many have faced. See the answers to this question to get the idea of how to overcome it- [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563277/passing-values-in-for-loop-to-event-listeners-javascript)

Comment: To make it more clear, see that the addListener statement has been moved out of the for loop into a separate function and the function is called in the loop.